# How does lattice package in R create gridlines automatically?

Tags: r, lme4, lattice

In the context of linear mixed effects model, it is extremely useful to plot residuals vs. fitted values to check homoscedasticity (of residuals). When I am using `lme4::plot.merMod` to plot such a figure, if I understand correctly, `lme4` uses `lattice` to produce the figure. For example, if we regress **hp** on **mpg**  with **carb** (from `tidyverse::mtcars`) as random effects*, we get a following plot:

[image]

I don't know, however, how `lattice` comes up with grey-color horizontal and vertical gridlines and if they represent any statistical aspect about model fit. If `lattice` just divides the x- and y-axis in four equal parts with these gridlines, how can I achieve such equally-spaced gridlines that consider x- and y-axis range in a base R plot?

Code to reproduce the figure:

```
library(lme4)
library(tidyverse)
model <- lme4::lmer(data = mtcars, formula = mpg ~ hp + (1 | gear))
plot(model, aspect = 1)
```

*I am not concerned about correct model specification at the moment.

Comment: As far as I can see in the very complex code of `lme4:::plot.merMod` the grid is specified by `panel.grid` with default arguments. Read `help("panel.grid")`. The grid has no statistical meaning.

Comment: `graphics::grid()` might work but doesn't work exactly the same as `lattice::panel.grid()` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, this can be done by using `graphics::grid` (as suggested by [Prof. Bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76826688/how-does-lattice-package-in-r-create-gridlines-automatically/76829429?noredirect=1#comment135443477_76826688)):

```
library(lme4)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom.mixed)

model <- lme4::lmer(data = mtcars, formula = mpg ~ hp + (1 | gear))
data <- broom.mixed::augment(model)

par(pty='s')    # to keep aspect ratio 1
plot(data$.fixed, data$.resid)
graphics::grid(nx = 4, lty = 1)
```

Or by directly using:

```
plot(data$.fixed, data$.resid, panel.first = grid(4, lty = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The gridlines are produced by the call to [`grid::grid.segments`](https://rdrr.io/r/grid/grid.segments.html) inside `lattice::panel.grid` (see [lattice::panel.grid](https://github.com/deepayan/lattice/blob/e2f44f54c40204737e6e7689904801fbea5df67d/R/panels.R#L338)).

When [`lme4::plot.merMod`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/lme4.pdf) is called, it calls `lattice::panel.grid`, which in turn calls `grid::grid.segments(h = 3, v = 3, ...)`. This results in partitioning the viewport in four equal parts - horizontally as well as  vertically - by three horizontal and three vertical lines.

I provide a figure below, drawn using [`grid`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/doc/grid.pdf), that might confirm this:

```
library(lme4)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom.mixed)

model <- lme4::lmer(data = mtcars, formula = mpg ~ hp + (1 | gear))
data <- broom.mixed::augment(model)

v <- 3    # to reproduce default call to panel.grid
grid.newpage()
vp <- viewport(width=unit(3, "inches"), height=unit(3, "inches"))
pushViewport(vp)
pushViewport(dataViewport(data$.fitted, data$.resid))
grid.rect()
grid.xaxis()
grid.yaxis()
grid.text("LU", x=unit(0, "npc"), y=unit(1, "npc"), gp=gpar(col="red"))
grid.text("LB", x=unit(0,"npc"), y=unit(0, "npc"), gp=gpar(col="red"))
grid.text("1", x=unit(0.25,"npc"), y=unit(0, "npc"), gp=gpar(col="blue"))
grid.text("2", x=unit(0.5,"npc"), y=unit(0, "npc"), gp=gpar(col="darkgreen"))
grid.text("3", x=unit(0.75,"npc"), y=unit(0, "npc"), gp=gpar(col="darkred"))
grid.points(x=data$.fitted, y=data$.resid)
grid.segments(x0 = 1:v / (v+1),
              x1 = 1:v / (v+1),
              gp = gpar(col = "pink", lty = 2, lwd = 2),
              default.units = "npc")
grid.segments(y0 = 1:v / (v+1),
              y1 = 1:v / (v+1),
              gp = gpar(col = "orange", lty = 3, lwd = 2),
              default.units = "npc")
pushViewport(vp)
```

The red colored texts *LB* and *LU* show left-bottom and left-upper corners of the viewport. The colored numbers 1, 2, and 3 overlapping on x-axis are placed at 0.25 npc, 0.5 npc and 0.75 npc away from *LB* i.e. the origin of the viewport, respectively. This is because *npc** means:

> Normalised Parent Coordinates. Treats the bottom-left corner of the current viewport as the
> location (0, 0) and the top-right corner as (1, 1).

We see that the call (in the above code) to `grid.segments` plots lines that overlap with these colored numbers.

[image]

---

*See Table 1 in [grid Graphics](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/doc/grid.pdf).

Comment: This is useful but doesn't answer the OP's main question: "how can I achieve such equally-spaced gridlines that consider x- and y-axis range in a base R plot?"